# Is there a way to import reddit data or any JSON formatted data into Firebase and use that data in Angular2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, reddit

I have created a new project app on Firebase Console and clicked on database.

I don't want to insert data into the database by manually inserting it. I need to know if I can import a JSON formatted data or redddits API data. (I have not yet created a project) I just want to get the database set up first. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Import a .json file through the Firebase Console.

1. Just select a project (you need to create a project).
2. Click on Database. It will open the DATA tab automatically.

[image]

3. Click the More Options button (see image below), you'll have an option to Import JSON.

[image]

To test it out. I made a sample .json file with the following contents:

```
{

"sample": "sample",
"sample2": "sample2"

}
```

Uploaded the file then refreshed the page. Result is this:

[image]

For the Reddit API part, I haven't used it before so I'm unable to provide any comments. But AFAIK, so long as it's a valid .json file with a correct JSON structure, it should import properly.